Bitwise operator options for a non-gawk awk like mawk?
I would like to make my (g)awk scripts more portable, especially to mawk, since it's Debian's stock awk.
I've always avoided things like length(array), and used array[outer, inner] for multidimensional arrays instead of array[inner][outer] (gawk's real multi arrays, not the SUBSEP hack).
But now I'm at an impasse with bit operators like and() and lshift(), which gawk provides, but mawk does not. How can I re-implement these for mawk, ideally without having to use the shell?
The wikibook (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK#Bit_manipulation) just says:

Traditional awk does not have bitwise operators to provide bit manipulation. However, gawk has bit manipulation functions built in, including and(), or(), xor(), compl(), lshift() and rshift().


Could someone add 'mawk' and 'gawk' tags? I tried, but SE won't let me, for some reason (new contributor?).

The gawk tag is a synonym to the awk tag. I don't think we need tags for each variant of awk.

If you need gawk, just use gawk... otherwise search for some ideas? Or just avoid using them altogether…

If the use case requires advanced features like bitwise operations, consider using Perl instead. It was developed to expand on the ideas and has a similar syntax to shell, awk and related languages, but it is much more advanced.

Only fedorafan can explain, but I read this as assuming there is a common, standard approach often used to do this in mawk, and asking what that would be, @EdMorton. Fedorafan, I suspect the real answer will be "don't use mawk" if you need to do something like this. In 2023, it is extremely unlikely that mawk is the best language for whatever you are doing that requires this sort of operator.

You could do this in POSIX awk using the 'int()' function and '%' (modulus) to implement functions with those names.  Someone with an afternoon to spare may provide a demonstration.

The bit shift operators are easy enough, just multiply or divide by the corresponding power of two.
The or/and/xor can be implemented using a loop where the result is summed successively for each bit, from least to most significant, e.g., for logical and:
result       += (((first_number % 2) * (second_number % 2)) % 2) * exponent
first_number  = int(first_number / 2)
second_number = int(second_number / 2)
exponent     *= 2

For or/xor, you replace the first multiplication in the first line with addition, and test the result to see if it's >= 2, changing it to 1 for logical or and 0 for xor.

YMMV multiplying or dividing, especially for large numbers, since awk uses floating point arithmetic for all math operations. If I were to implement this I'd use conversion to/from bits and string functions instead of math, e.g. see awk-convert-decimal-to-binary as a starting point. A guiding principle of the awk language is to only introduce constructs to do things that aren't easy to do with other constructs so the language remains small but powerful so if the gawk providers introduced functions for anything, it's probably not easy without them
